# The memory is 100% full and the postgresql service does not start, what can I do in this situation?

Tags: linux, database, memory, var

Can i delete last files from postgresql/base? If you delete the last created file, will the entire database structure be violated and will the database start after? The memory is 100% full and the postgresql service does not start, what can I do in this situation? I would be very happy if you help.

Comment: Deleting files usually doesn't free memory. You need to stop the process that's eating the memory.

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: the problem is in physical memory, the base size has become too large